# Why can I not delete this pesky Drop Down from a Sheet in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I am trying to delete a drop down from a spreadsheet using the following code:

```
Dim objShape As Shape
For Each objShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    objShape.Delete
Next
```

But `objShape` returns `Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error`:

`Debug.Print objShape.FormControlType` returns `xlDropDown`
`Debug.Print objShape.Name`                       returns `"Drop Down 250"`
`Debug.Print objShape.TopLeftCell`         returns `Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error`

`ActiveSheet.Cells.Validation.Delete` does not get rid of it, nor does using `ShapeRange`.

Any suggestions on how to eradicate this little bugger would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drop down list was tied to another sheet in the workbook. After deleting the other sheet, the code correctly deleted the shape.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ideas:

- Is there some sheet protection?
- Is the dropdown part of some validation (allowed values can be defined and are usually displayed as a dropdown box).